# How does 'rate' property of JavaFX Animation class behave?

Tags: animation, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have two rectangle shapes which are in translate transition as below

```
    //First rectangle animation
    TranslateTransition translateTransition1 = new TranslateTransition();
    translateTransition1.setNode(rect1);
    translateTransition1.setFromX(10);
    translateTransition1.setFromY(0);
    translateTransition1.setToX(10);
    translateTransition1.setToY(300);
    translateTransition1.setCycleCount(8);
    //translateTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
    translateTransition1.play();
    translateTransition1.setRate(0.1);

    //Second rectangle animation
    TranslateTransition translateTransition2 = new TranslateTransition();
    translateTransition2.setNode(rect2);
    translateTransition2.setFromX(10);
    translateTransition2.setFromY(-300);  // This is the only difference
    translateTransition2.setToX(10);
    translateTransition2.setToY(300);
    translateTransition2.setCycleCount(8);
    //translateTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
    translateTransition2.play();
    translateTransition2.setRate(0.1);
```

Here both of these animation has rate (0.1) but they moved at different speed when I run the application.

- As per the oracle document, 'rate' property defines speed/direction of the animation, then why does the two TranslateTranslations not have same speed even though I set it to 0.1?
- Also how is the actual behaviour of the 'rate' property?

Comment: You set the rate (and fromX) on translateTransition1 twice.  I don't think you want to do that.  I do think you want to set a Duration for each animation - then it will be easier for somebody to explain what rate does.

Comment: I have made the correction.But still the speed are different. I don't want to set duration. I just want the two rectangle to move at same speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Definition of Rate**

Rate is not the velocity or speed in pixels per second of the translated object in the transition.

Think of rate like this (courtesy of Louis Tully in Ghostbusters):

> I see you were exercising. So was I. I taped '20 Minute Workout' and played it back at high speed so it only took ten minutes and I got a really good workout.

Rate is like a fast forward, slow motion or rewind feature on a video recorder.

**The Definition of Speed**

> I don't want to set duration. I just want the two rectangle to move at same speed.

Speed is distance over time.

If you want your rectangles to move at the same speed, make them move the same distance for the same duration.

**Issues with your sample code**

If you don't set a duration, one will be assigned for you.  The default duration is 400 milliseconds, which is probably not what you want.

The rectangles in your question are moving at different speeds because you have asked them to travel different distances in the same time span.

**Example**

OK, you have probably got it now, but here is an example just in case.

```
TranslateTransition translateTransition1 = new TranslateTransition(
  Duration.seconds(1), rect1
);
translateTransition1.setFromX(0);
translateTransition1.setToX(100);
translateTransition1.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
translateTransition1.play();

TranslateTransition translateTransition2 = new TranslateTransition(
  Duration.seconds(2), rect2
);
translateTransition2.setFromX(0);
translateTransition2.setToX(100);
translateTransition2.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
translateTransition2.play();

rect2.setTranslateY(200);
```

So there are two rectangles:

- `rect1` moves a total distance of 100 pixels in one second, so its speed of travel is 100 pixels per second.
- `rect2` moves a total distance of 100 pixels in two seconds, so its speed of travel is 50 pixels per second.

A linear interpolator is used so that the transitions occur at constant velocity (e.g. a given rectangle does not accelerate or decelerate while it is moving).

If you want both rectangles to move at the same speed, you could set the duration of the second transition to one second, so it matches the duration of the first transition (their distance travelled already matches).

Alternatively, if you invoke `translateTransition2.setRate(2)`, the second animation will play twice as quick, thus finishing in half of it's duration.  This will double the speed of travel from 50 pixels per second to 100 pixels per second, matching the speed of the first rectangle.